# Elasticsearch: how to figure out the total time of a flag status?

Tags: node.js, database, elasticsearch

My index includes documents like the following rows:

```
 |    changed_at    |  mood  | user |
 ------------------------------
 | yyyy-mm-dd 12:00 | sad    | John |
 | yyyy-mm-dd 15:00 | happy  | John |
 | yyyy-mm-dd 18:00 | happy  | John |
 |        ...       |   ...  |  ... |
```

The user can **change it's mood**, duplicates *(e.g. two times "sad" in a row)* are logged as well.

I would like to know **how many hours a day** the users are **happy or sad**. I'm aware that the following **formula is not precise**:

1. John started to be sad at 12:00
2. and became happy at 15:00, which means he was sad for 3 hours.
3. At 18:00 he confirmed being happy.

From 12:00 until the next mood change, we expect John to be happy *(3 hours sad, 21 hours happy)*.

Does **elasticsearch** offer **features** for queries like that **or do I have to loop** all the results and calculate the gap between the state changes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you index a new mood, you should probably also index the time duration between two contributions if the two moods are different.

Comment: @Val Good idea, thanks. I was hoping to be able to use a filter and let ES do all the calculation.

Comment: You can definitely do all this with ES, but the solution will certainly involve several queries, whereas precomputing the most you can in advance would certainly bring huge benefits.